# Trying to add a contact using External API on WHMCS

Tags: php, api, whmcs

I am trying to add a new contact using the external API on WHMCS, given the code below

```
<?php

//API Connection
$url = "http://localhost:81/whmcs/includes/api.php";
$username = "admin";
$password = "password";

//Add the contact
$postfields = array();
$postfields["username"] = $username;
$postfields["password"] = md5($password);
$postfields["action"] = 'Addcontact';
$postfields["clientid"] = '1';
$postfields["firstname"] = 'abc';
$postfields["lastname"] = "def";
$postfields["email"] = "abc@def.com";

$query_string = "";
foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) $query_string .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$jsondata = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) die("Connection Error: ".curl_errno($ch).' -      '.curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);    
$arr = json_decode($jsondata);

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Unfortunately it is not getting added at the admin end. Any help?

Comment: do the admin user you are using to make the API call have the API Access permission? Also try setting the variable $postfields['responsetype'] = 'json'; You could also view the documentation herehttp://developers.whmcs.com/api/sample-code/

Comment: Yes, the admin has the API permission.

Answer (score 2):

The action is "AddContact" not "Addcontact" .

https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/addcontact/